# Length of the arc of the curve from the origin to the point.

Tags: derivatives, arc-length

We have $\left \{ X(t),Y(t) \right \}, 1\leq t\leq \pi$ defined by the following two definite integral:

$X(t)=\int_{1}^{t}\frac{\cos z}{z^2}dz, Y(t)=\int_{1}^{t}\frac{\sin z}{z^2}dz$

$L$ be the length of the arc of the curve from the origin to the point $P$ on the curve at which the tangent is perpendicular to the x-axis. Then, the $L$ will be equal to?

I took the derivative of both $X(t),Y(t)$ using the Leibniz rule and then found the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as follows:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan (t)$

I am thinking of using the following formula for the length of the curve:
$\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} dx$

But I am unable to find what will be the upper limit of the above integral. Any help to find the upper limit will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Notice you have written $dy/dx$ as a function of $t$, not $x$.

Comment: What is $f$ ? I would have used $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{X'^2\left(t\right)+Y'^2\left(t\right)}\text{d}t$.

Comment: Should it be function of $x$, I think I have calculated it correctly.

Comment: The two comments above should be enough to answer: when the tangent is orthogonal to the $x$ axis, what does is mean for $\tan t$? Then find $t$, it's your upper bound in Atmos' integral. The lower bound, however, is not $0$: $X=Y=0$ for $t=1$.

Comment: $tan t$ is undefined when tangent is orthogonal. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, and that happens if $t=$?

Comment: That is when $π/2$

Comment: So does that mean upper bound is $π/2$

Comment: Yeah, I got my answers. You both explained this concept quite well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I find that doing this analysis in the complex plane simplifies it somewhat. First let me alter the notation in order to avoid confusion with the complex varaible $z$. To that end, let's write

$$
X(t)=\int_{1}^{t}\frac{\cos u}{u^2}du\\
Y(t)=\int_{1}^{t}\frac{\sin u}{u^2}du
$$

Now we can express the complex variable as

$$z(t)=\int_{1}^{t}\frac{e^{iu}}{u^2}du$$

The arc length is given as follows in the complex plane,

$$s=\int |\dot z| dt$$

From Leibniz's rule

$$
\dot z=\frac{e^{it}}{t^2}\\
|\dot z|=\frac{1}{t^2}
$$

And finally,

$$s=\int_1^T \frac{1}{t^2} dt=1-\frac{1}{T}$$

I have verified this result numerically (in comparison with the integral). Also note that WolframAlpha gives $\int_1^{\infty} 1/t^2 dt=1$.